# How to add selected songs from music gallery in android

Tags: android

I want to open the music gallery and then add the selected song to a list.After selecting the song,will move to another screen.After that I want to play the selected songs one by one.
I tried the below code but it open the library and play the selected song once clicked.

```
final Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
          intent2.setType("audio/*");
          startActivityForResult(intent2, 1);
```

Thanks in advace.

Comment: what is the issue.please elaborate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a filter on the items you want to fetch from Sdcard and add the items to Array list as:

```
    ArrayList<String> music_list = new ArrayList<String>();

    musiclist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    final String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getPath();

    File file = new File(filepath, "Audio_Songs_Folder");

    String[] a = file.list(new FilenameFilter() {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String filename)

        {
            return (filename.endsWith(".mp4") ||filename.endsWith(".mp3"));

        }
    });

    for (String string : a)

    {

        music_list .add(string);

    }
```

Here Audio_Songs_Folder is the folder from where you want to fetch the songs.

Comment: I want to fetch the songs which is in our music library.I tried to fetch the song from sd card but the songs are in different folder in different phones.

Comment: now you want to fetch the music files from the sdcard folders?

Comment: I want to open the music library and then fetch the selected item from there